# wordpress pagination not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have custom query on my wordpress page. Query looks like this:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'tworca' ),
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'posts_per_page'=>12,
  'post_parent' => 0
);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args['paged'] = $paged;
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   $the_query->the_post();
   ... this is content of my query.....
 }
?>
<nav>
  <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
  <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
  <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
  </nav>
 <?php
} else {
  echo 'no results';
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

But my pagination doesn't show. Any idea why? I have read many posts with similar problem, but solution always was to add 'paged' parameter to wp query. And I have this parameter in my query and it doesn't help.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try by adding your query object to the wp_pagenavi(), which would be like,

```
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query ) );
```

Reference: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/wpn-2-74.html

Comment: As simple as that :) Thank you, works like a charm! :)

Comment: There must be more to this. "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_pagenavi()"

Answer (score 1):

Try This..
`$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $args = array( 
                'posts_per_page'    =>  12,
                'paged'             =>  $paged,
                'orderby'           => 'title',
                'order'             => 'ASC',
                'post_parent'       => 0,
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
            );
            query_posts( $args );
            if ( have_posts() ) {
            $i = 0;
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post();

`Your data here you want display like title`
the_title();
}

```
                    wp_pagenavi();
                }
                wp_reset_query();
            ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `wp_pagenavi()` to `wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $the_query) );`